# Why do my xcode builds always go to the iPad simulator instead of the iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, ipad

I just installed the latest SDK from Apple so I can start learning iPhone / iPad app development. However, I'm having a stupid issue: all my builds get run in the iPad simulator instead of the iPhone simulator, and I have no idea how to change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For now, the iPhone Simulator 3.2 SDK is iPad-only. Test using the iPhone Simulator 3.1.2 SDK

edit: as of the upcoming 4.2 SDK, the iPhone and iPad versions of iOS have been unified under a single SDK.

Comment: Was just about to ask the same question (thought it was a configuration problem) and saw this answer. I'd been digging through the target and executable settings for days trying to find this. Didn't expect something so simple.

Answer (score 9):

On your build selector dropdown, (where you select device or simulator), there's now a new option that lets you choose the "Active Executible." Choose "iPhone Simulator."

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100227-qyadm4ktn3abr3j44upkufjieh.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100227-qyadm4ktn3abr3j44upkufjieh.jpg)

Comment: I don't have this option, only iPad simulator is listed.

Comment: change the active sdk to 3.1.2