# How can I stop Xcode 3.2.6 defaulting to the iPad Simulator? Is this new behaviour?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode3.2

It seems like every time I launch an Xcode project or 'Clean all Targets' the Active Executable resets to the iPad simulator.

Prior to the Xcode 3.2.6 release Xcode was defaulting to the iPhone Simulator or remembered my previous Active Executable... I've never noticed this behaviour because I generally do iPhone work. This has been bothering me sine the latest Xcode update (iOS 4.3 release) and is *really* irritating.

Similar questions/answers suggest setting the 'Targeted Device Family' of my Target to 'iPhone' - this has been done.

Is this new behaviour?

Is there anyway to change the default 'Active Executable'?

Comment: I Post this just as a comment, because it's not really an answer. I suggest you to upgrade to Xcode4. It's really nice to work with it. ;-)

Comment: I'm well aware of XCode 4, but unfortunately Xcode 3.2.6 is a requirement for a current project :)

Comment: I guess Xcode 3.2.5 is not an appropriate solution. For me 3.2.5 had exactly the opposite problem, it was switching to iphone all the time.

Comment: I moved to XCode 4 on release. I couldn't stand it. Broke 1/2 of my projects, OVERRODE the XCode3 install. They made every frequently used menu option hidden 5000 levels deep. Yuck. Reinstalled XCode3 ASAP.

Comment: This isn't a discussion about XCode4 vs XCode3. I use both, and find the details of my question annoying with Xcode3.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's driving me nuts, and it's new in Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 5):

I tried some options and at the end I figured out a workaround that doesn't default to iPad simulator, but it uses SDK4.2 and always defaults back to the iPhone 4.2 Simulator.

I hope this works on your machine too and maybe sdk4.2 is good enough for you.

1. Option-Click the build configuration overview menu (or whatever it's true name is)
2. Select iOS Simulator 4.2 as Active SDK
3. Select iPhone Simulator 4.2 as Active Executable
4. Build
5. Clean/Reopen/Whatever
6. Build again and the iPhone simulator should be starting.

[image]

As I said, it uses SDK4.2, but imho it's better to use SDK4.2 than to switch to the iPad simulator each time you open/clean/... the project.

After you've compiled for the device (which switches the sdk to the base sdk) you have to redo the workaround.

Afaik there is no real solution for the problem. It exists in different variants for more than 6 months. Until the current xcode3 version for me it was switching back to iPhone simulator all the time. For other users it was defaulting to iPad.

There are more than a dozen threads in the apple dev forums. None of them offers a solution, or even a workaround.

---

You should file a bug at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/) and pray that xcode3 isn't considered end of life.

Comment: +1 Works, 4.2 is good enough for me, still, I am furious about this. Those little things make my developing life worse.

Answer (score 2):

From [How to change the default Xcode iphone simulator when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643298/how-to-change-the-default-xcode-iphone-simulator-when-testing) and [Why do my xcode builds always go to the iPad simulator instead of the iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349142/why-do-my-xcode-builds-always-go-to-the-ipad-simulator-instead-of-the-iphone-simu):

Try changing the base SDK to 4.0 or higher.

Comment: what does "Active SDK" mean?  do you mean the "Base SDK" in the Build settings? or the "deployment target" SDK?

Answer (score 0):

do yo have two xcode (or iphone sdk) installation on your machine? if yes then completely uninstall the xcode using this command -

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

from all the locations (replace Developer with installed directory name)

and install the xcode 3.2.6 in developer directory

Comment: I'll give it a try the first chance I get,

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of xCode, which is xCode 4.

Then set project scheme to iphone simulator and run app in xCode several times.

And re-install xCode 3 and the problem will be gone away!