# Xcode 3.2.6 with ios 4.3, problem with active executable

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, executable, ios4

when i run the XCODE with ios 4.3 the default simulator is set to ipad ....I changed  active executable setting to iphone simulator .. but stil its not working ..Whenever i open the XCODE again its restting back to ipad .. Is ther any other way to set this out ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404262/how-can-i-stop-xcode-3-2-6-defaulting-to-the-ipad-simulator-is-this-new-behaviou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building the app in the iPhone simulator, wait until the iPad finishes loading; if your app is displayed and working properly then (and only then) try switching to the iPhone simulator.

To keep the iPhone display as the default, try changing the program preferences from the simulator itself or from the Xcode project file in Xcode.